# httprouter configuring NotFound

Tags: http, go, url-routing

I'm using [`httprouter`](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) for an API and I'm trying to work out how to handle 404s. It does say in the [docs](http://godoc.org/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter#Router.NotFound) that 404's can be handled manually but I don't really have an idea how to write my own **custom handler**.

I've tried the following after my other routes...

```
router.NotFound(pageNotFound)
```

But I get the error `not enough arguments in call to router.NotFound`.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type [`httprouter.Router`](http://godoc.org/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter#Router) is a `struct` which has a field:

```
NotFound http.Handler
```

So type of `NotFound` is [`http.Handler`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler), an interface type which has a single method:

```
ServeHTTP(ResponseWriter, *Request)
```

If you want your own custom "Not Found" handler, you have to set a value that implements this interface.

The easiest way is to define a function with signature:

```
func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)
```

And use the [`http.HandlerFunc()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) helper function to "convert" it to a value that implements the `http.Handler` interface, whose `ServeHTTP()` method simply calls the function with the above signature.

For example:

```
func MyNotFound(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound) // StatusNotFound = 404
    w.Write([]byte("My own Not Found handler."))
    w.Write([]byte(" The page you requested could not be found."))
}

var router *httprouter.Router = ... // Your router value
router.NotFound = http.HandlerFunc(MyNotFound)
```

This `NotFound` handler will be invoked by the `httprouter` package. If you would want to call it manually from one of your other handlers, you would have to pass a [`ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) and a [`*Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) to it, something like this:

```
func ResourceHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    exists := ... // Find out if requested resource is valid and available
    if !exists {
        MyNotFound(w, r) // Pass ResponseWriter and Request
        // Or via the Router:
        // router.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }

    // Resource exists, serve it
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @miestasmia Thanks for the note, I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

NotFound is a function pointer of type http.HandlerFunc. You will have to put a function with the signature `Func(w ResponseWriter, r *Request)` somewhere and assign it to NotFound (`router.NotFound = Func`).