# httprouter setting custom NotFound

Tags: go

I'm using https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter in my Go project.

I asked this question a while back which was solved by @icza: [httprouter configuring NotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500322/httprouter-configuring-notfound) but now, starting a new project and using very similar code I appear to be getting errors in the console.

Trying to configure custom handlers `NotFound` and `MethodNotAllowed` I'm using:

```
router.NotFound = customNotFound
router.MethodNotAllowed = customMethodNotAllowed
```

produces:

```
cannot use customNotFound (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) as type http.Handler in assignment:                                                                               
        func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)                                                                                                   

cannot use customMethodNotAllowed (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) as type http.Handler in assignment:                                                                       
        func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)
```

My functions look like this:

```
func customNotFound(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    core.WriteError(w, "PAGE_NOT_FOUND", "Requested resource could not be found")
    return
}

func customMethodNotAllowed(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    core.WriteError(w, "METHOD_NOT_PERMITTED", "Request method not supported by that resource")
    return
}
```

Has there been some breaking changes in this package in the last couple of months as I can't work out why I'm getting the error in one project and not in the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since commit 70708e4600 in httprouter the `router.NotFound` is no longer a `http.HandlerFunc` but a `http.Handler`. So you will have to adapt your functions with via http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc if you use a recent commit of httprouter.

The following should work (untested):

```
router.NotFound = http.HandlerFunc(customNotFound)
```