# setup 404 NotFound handler on a gorilla mux router

Tags: go, gorilla, mux

Here is my code about a small demonstration webserver written with the Go language and the gorilla mux package  :

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", vars["username"])
}

func homeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        errorHandler(w, r, http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", vars["username"])
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/help/{username}/", handler)
    http.Handle("/", r)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

But I don't find a way on how to implement a custom 404 page.

But I can't make a r.HandleFunc("/",...)   but it will be too greedy.

Comment: For serving a custom error page yourself, see [httprouter configuring NotFound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500322/httprouter-configuring-notfound/30500491#30500491).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Router](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router) exports a `NotFoundHandler` field which you can set to your custom handler.

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.NotFoundHandler = MyCustom404Handler
```

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes, you spend a lot of time building a stack of middleware that does many things like logging, sending metrics and so... And the default 404 handler just skips all the middlewares.

I was able to solve this issue by re-setting the default 404 handler like this:

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.Use(someMiddleware())
// Re-define the default NotFound handler
router.NotFoundHandler = router.NewRoute().HandlerFunc(http.NotFound).GetHandler()
```

Now, the 404 default handler is also going thru all the middlewares.

Comment: Cool solution. But you have to do this assigning either after declaring your real routes or by using `BuildOnly()` method to prevent this route from acting like a wildcard.

Comment: Works, but You should define this NotFoundHandler registered once all the handlers are registered, otherwise, it will override all the handlers

Answer (score 2):

Set the [`NotFoundHandler`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router) to a handler method that returns your custom 404 page.

Answer (score 2):

```
r := mux.NewRouter()

h := http.HandlerFunc(NotFound)
r.NotFoundHandler = h
    
func NotFound(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about what this does